# Struggling with react routing

Tags: reactjs

when i try to route in react js using parameter the browser is throwing error: 'GET http://localhost:3000/store/build/main.js 
123:24 GET http://localhost:3000/store/build/main.js 404 (Not Found)'
and the contents of component are not displayed,
otherwise (without the parameters) it works just fine,
what may the reason be?

Answer (score 0):

You have to place `/` before `main.js`. So you code have to look something like this:

```
<script src="/app.js"></script>
```

Add `publicPath` parameter to your `webpack.config.js` file:

```
output: {
    path: distPath,
    publicPath: '/',
    filename: 'js/[name].js'
}
```